# pandas: add new column with value from either of two other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame({'A':[None,2,None,None,3,4],'B':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})

     A  B
0  NaN  1
1    2  2
2  NaN  3
3  NaN  4
4    3  5
5    4  6
```

how do I add column `C` that will take the value from column `A` if it's not NaN, otherwise column `B`'s value?

```
     A  B  C
0  NaN  1  1
1    2  2  2
2  NaN  3  3
3  NaN  4  4
4    3  5  3
5    4  6  4
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try [combine_first()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
In [184]: a['C'] = a['A'].combine_first(a['B']).astype(int)

In [185]: a
Out[185]:
     A  B  C
0  NaN  1  1
1  2.0  2  2
2  NaN  3  3
3  NaN  4  4
4  3.0  5  3
5  4.0  6  4
```

Comment: Cool.  Though, technically, you may want to change the doc link to this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html.

Comment: @DmitryB., thanks for pointing that out, i've updated the link

Answer (score 4):

you could also try [fillna()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
In [26]: a['C'] = a['A'].fillna(a['B'])

In [27]: a
Out[27]:
     A  B  C
0  NaN  1  1
1    2  2  2
2  NaN  3  3
3  NaN  4  4
4    3  5  3
5    4  6  4
```